# How to find the private key from following data with aes-128-ctr encryption?

Tags: cryptography, aes, ethereum, private-key

with following data how could I get the private key?

```
{"address":"6f1f586c60b67d01a712f5779e000bb89effab29","blspublickey":"751add68b0a46803a9528977de638effaa21223a6bb7e5ee755d9395be33ac5755f34be1d9e42979fb1d5682e71d9f0174a1649d50c03eccc6254986a2dbdf96ec0c464f339ef65c63ed028d0da62239cc219ae068820602b7da039e41503381","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"7857ef99553a6a71b61b5adddaf07727fac5309313b83d8ae3c6d04c55ebbcdc","cipherparams":{"iv":"346d17a58e0ab636123a68d191dca7e8"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":4096,"p":6,"r":8,"salt":"470fa1f30d3695ce93a5ed83bbbd5f13d78d69c38e54b58335206b8eb22bbbdf"},"mac":"a92016a599f867162836f157da5400a63dcb7b6327e0de62e25c2ea2846d3c61"},"id":"710e9b7a-5af7-4d1e-9a01-75f414566c59","version":3}
```

Comment: AES is a symmetric algorithm, there's no public or private key.

Comment: `scrypt` is a Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF). The AES key is derived from a password given de KDF parameters. bereal is right of course, the key of a symmetric algorithm is usually called a secret key (although in this case the password and thus the derived key may be kept by one person and be private on top of being secret).

Answer (score 1):

## Ethereum

In your case, your solution seems:

- to be here (when using **Node.js**): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/72342/91560

  - It seems to be using a function `keythereum.recover(..)`
- to be impossible (when using **[geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options)**):

  - The documentation doesn't mention a way to export the private key: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/managing-your-accounts
  - I found a website saying it's impossible with **geth**, and that you need Metamask:

> "geth" does not offer commands to export private key out of an Ethereum account. If you really want to get the private key, you can import the keystore file to MetaMask wallet. You can then export the private key from MetaMask wallet.

Source: [http://www.herongyang.com/Ethereum/Etheruem-Account-geth-Commands.html#:~:text=%22geth%22%20does%20not%20offer%20commands,private%20key%20from%20MetaMask%20wallet](http://www.herongyang.com/Ethereum/Etheruem-Account-geth-Commands.html#:%7E:text=%22geth%22%20does%20not%20offer%20commands,private%20key%20from%20MetaMask%20wallet).

## Harmony

Concerning a similar case, for Harmony, you would also end up (after account creation) with a keystore file similar to your:

```
{
    "address": "b1fe3715a3...6db7703afb1",
    "crypto": {
        "cipher": "aes-128-ctr",
        "ciphertext": "e8a64100be0df0ffb3...2c56f38816c5db89",
        "cipherparams": {
            "iv": "fb04cf5400...c4a0d3118"
        },
        "kdf": "scrypt",
        "kdfparams": {
            "dklen": 32,
            "n": 262144,
            "p": 1,
            "r": 8,
            "salt": "376010403c825eae97...c737a08219e9dd137e12a5ef022"
        },
        "mac": "c68aa6e1d8eab7973d21...ee68316483d9b0e"
    },
    "id": "0000...2cd38a67",
    "version": 3
}
```

This file (above) is created by

- running `./hmy keys add test-account2 --passphrase`
- then entering a passphrase (password).
- You will be given a Harmony ONE address and a mnemonic.

**NB**: **passphrase** is short, **mnemonic** is long one made of many words.

--> FINALLY, to get/display the private key after account creation, you would:

- run `./hmy keys export-private-key one14q2lmu...mgfwkk95jt --passphrase`
- enter the passphrase (password).
- You will be given the private key of you account

Documentation for Harmony command line (`./hmy`) is here: https://docs.harmony.one/home/network/wallets/harmony-cli/create-import-wallet

### Harmony vocabulary

- **Passphrase**: this is your password; the piece of text made of one word,

  - similar to: "Salsa74?PePper"
- **Mnemonic**: this is sometimes called "secret recovery phrase" (by Metamask); the piece of text made of several words,

  - similar to: "pepper house bell door paper cat board wall"